# How can I use Datatable.compute() with list of data

Tags: c#, datatable

I want to add values within list of dates using datatable.compute.

List of dates as follows

```
var dates = Enumerable.Range(0, 7).Select(days => monday.AddDays(days)).ToList();
```

And I want compute the values in those days.I don't know how to use filter with the list.
I've tried following method but no luck.

```
sumObject1 = table.Compute("Sum(Amount)", "Type='Income' AND Date = dates");
```

Rest of the code works fine.

Comment: you need to add `dates` to `table` as its column values first. `Compute` is unaware of any data outside `table`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ for that:

```
 table.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r["Type"]?.ToString() == "Income" && dates.Contains((DateTime)r["Date"]))
.Sum(rs => (decimal)rs["Amount"]);
```

You won't be able to use the list with the DataTable expressions.